# Postgres & Javascript - How to format object array in Nodejs to be inserted into Postgres JSON column?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I have an array of objects in Javascript:

```
const testArray = [{name: 'John', date: '2017-03-15'}, {name: 'Bob', date: '2018-04-29'}];
```

And in nodejs I am running an `UPDATE` statement that goes to my Postgres DB. I need to insert the above array of objects into a JSON Array column in Postgres. It needs to look like the following:

```
UPDATE persons
SET info = (array['{"name": "John", "date": "2017-03-15"}', '{"name": "John", "date": "2018-04-29"}']::json[])
WHERE id = 1;
```

The problem is I can't get it to look like that. When I try doing the following in nodejs:

```
UPDATE persons
SET info = (array[ ${ testArray } ]::json[])
WHERE id = 1;
```

It ends up looking like this when it is run:

```
UPDATE persons
SET info = (array[[object Object],[object Object]]::json[])
WHERE id = 1;
```

If I try using `JSON.stringify()` like so:

```
UPDATE persons
SET info = (array[ ${JSON.stringify(testArray) } ]::json[])
WHERE id = 1;
```

It looks like this when run:

```
UPDATE persons
SET info = (array[{"name": "John", "date": "2017-03-15"}, {"name": "John", "date": "2018-04-29"}]::json[])
WHERE id = 1;
```

Which is closer - it's just missing the single quotes that need to surround each object.

How can I format the array in nodejs correctly so that Postgres accepts it?

Comment: Did you try using `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Yes I did, and it still doesn't work (though it is closer to being correct). See my edit for result.

Comment: which postgres client library you are using?

Comment: I'm using node-postgres

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. First do the following to your array of objects:

```
const formatArray = finalArray.map(object => `'${JSON.stringify(object)}'`);
```

And now you can do this:

```
UPDATE persons
SET info = (array[ ${ formatArray } ]::json[])
WHERE id = 1;
```